# Get a list of all users who share my Facebook page's post

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I need the list of all users who share my Facebook page post. Is there any solution to get the whole list or details of all users who share my page's post?

Below the post here is a link showing 182 shares. We cannot see the details of all users who share my post, because some users have privacy set.

Can you guide me? Is their any solution through the Facebook API?

Comment: Read this -> http://stackoverflow.com/q/7748037/4248931

Answer (score 3):

You essentially answered the question yourself, this is a privacy concern and Facebook will not share this data. Facebook even has given an [official support answer on this question here](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10200351207448427). I will also copy their response in below:

> Thanks for your question. Posts about a Page respect the privacy
>   settings of the people who create them. Page admins won't see posts
>   about their Page that people haven't shared publicly even though
>   people visiting the Page might see them if they're part of the
>   audience the post was shared with. This includes those that have
>   shared content from your Page.
>
> You should also check out Facebook's Pages Terms and Promotion
>   Guidelines. This type of promotion is not allowed on Facebook, but can
>   be facilitated through a third party app if you choose. You can learn
>   more about running a promotion on Facebook in our Help Center here:
>   https://www.facebook.com/help/411018158926396/
>
> Thanks for your understanding, Rhett